# Error while converting from xls to xlsx using win32com. This program throws error if i work with other excel sheet

Tags: python-3.x, xlsx, win32com

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import win32com.client
import win32com.client.gencache
fname = "C:\\Users\\prashanth\\Desktop\\student.xls"
excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname)
wb.SaveAs(fname+"x", FileFormat = 51)    
wb.Close()                               
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\prashanth\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 536, in EnsureDispatch
    ti = disp.*oleobj*.GetTypeInfo()
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dailyreports2.py", line 6, in 
    excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
  File "c:\users\prashanth\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 547, in EnsureDispatch
    raise TypeError("This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object")
TypeError: This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object

Comment: Please post your updates in your question. Hard to read from your comments

Comment: i have updated in my question.

Comment: the above program works when other excel sheets are closed or saved ! but it doesnt work when i work with any other excel sheet

Comment: @Raptor any updates? am still stuck with this one

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error after these lines:

```
import win32com.client
import win32com.client.gencache
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

A machine restart worked for me.

Comment: I have gotten this error. Sometimes a restart worked. Another time, when a restart did not do the trick, I changed the code to `win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')` and it worked. No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the automated creation of folder of python scripts related to the com object. C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py

When you EnsureDispatch, that folder is created every time through makepy. When you Dispatch, it references a existing folder.

I'm dealing with the same issue and sometimes deleting the contents of 3.7 in the gen_py folder works. I'm still wrapping my head around it but am busy at work

[More info can be found in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127959/win32-dispatch-vs-win32-gencache-in-python-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)