# Using openpyxl to get column width from Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I need to get column widths from Excel and write them to a .txt file.  I believe openpyxl is the way to do it, but I cannot get the openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.ColumnDimension.width to return a value.  Is this the right approach?

Comment: try `print(ws.column_dimensions['A'].width)`

Comment: What have you actually tried to do?

Answer (score 1):

- Here is an alternate method, which instantiates Excel as an object.
- This only works on Windows, and if Excel is installed.

#### Given:

[image]

#### Code:

```py
import win32com.client as win32

filename = 'D:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/test.xlsx'

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False  # can be True if you like

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
ws1 = wb.Sheets('Sheet1')

for x in range(1, ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count +1):
    print(ws1.Columns(x).ColumnWidth)

wb.Close(True)
```

#### Output:

```
8.43
8.43
8.43
8.43
8.43
39.43
```

- `ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count` returns an `int` of the number of used columns, in the Excel screenshot A:F == 1:6
- `ws1.Columns(x).ColumnWidth` returns the column width
- Incidentally, using this method to interact with Excel exposes all Excel functions, allowing for interaction with new or existing files, graphing, formatting, etc.

  - If `excel.Visible = True`, operations can be performed on the live file while you watch; just don't interact with Excel with python is working on it.

Comment: what's the difference between win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch vs win32.client.Dispatch ?

Comment: Lucky for the both of us, that can be found at [win32.Dispatch vs win32.gencache in Python. What are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127959/win32-dispatch-vs-win32-gencache-in-python-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

Comment: Thank You !! In short difference would be, early binding vs late binding.

Comment: If you're interested, I have [Excel_Automation_with_Python](https://github.com/trenton3983/Excel_Automation_with_Python) with an example generating pivot tables.

Comment: Thank You Trenton, I will check...