# EOFError: Ran out of input when using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32

Recently, I tried using the python Excel functions on Windows with the win32com.client library. I installed it with :

```
pip install pywin32
```

I used it on my script, with simple commands like :

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32

ExcelApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
ExcelWrkBook = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook
ExcelWrkSht = ExcelWrkBook.ActiveSheet
ExcelWrkSht.Cells(5,3).Value = "something"
```

So it all worked just fine , till I got an Error like this out of nowhere :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "myscript.py", line 2, in 
>       import win32com.client as win32
>     File "C:\Users\Mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wi
>   n32com\client__init__.py", line 11, in 
>       from . import gencache
>     File "C:\Users\Mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wi
>   n32com\client\gencache.py", line 660, in 
>       **init**()
>     File "C:\Users\Mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wi
>   n32com\client\gencache.py", line 60, in **init**
>       _LoadDicts()
>     File "C:\Users\Mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wi
>   n32com\client\gencache.py", line 113, in _LoadDicts
>       version = p.load()
>   EOFError: Ran out of input

this pops up whenever I import win32com.client as win32, I tried reinstalling the library but it is still the same , Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a problem (client/ COM Server) communication, Solved by clearing the cache.

You can do it by deleting the gen_py folder "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py"

After debug the error was from GenCache. I am not that well informed with regards to these libraries but [I found this interesting thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127959/win32-dispatch-vs-win32-gencache-in-python-what-are-the-pros-and-cons) and replaced the gencache with Dispatch, so the Program changed to :

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32

ExcelApp = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
ExcelWrkBook = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook
ExcelWrkSht = ExcelWrkBook.ActiveSheet
ExcelWrkSht.Cells(5,3).Value = "something"
```