# Why does Python's version of Excel's Range.Resize not work as expected?

Tags: python, excel, vba, pywin32, win32com

In Excel VBA the code below selects the columns A to E.

```
worksheet.Columns(1).Resize(ColumnSize:=5).Select
```

But in Python (using the `win32com.client` module) the code below doesn't work.

```
worksheet.Columns(1).Resize(ColumnSize=5).Select()
# TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ColumnSize'

worksheet.Columns(1).Resize(ColumnIndex=5).Select()
# pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

While the code below only selects the column E.

```
worksheet.Columns(1).Resize(5).Select()
worksheet.Columns(1).Resize(RowIndex=5).Select()
```

Workaround in the code below (I don't want to use `worksheet.Columns('A:E')` because the number of columns varies).

```
worksheet.Range(Cell1=worksheet.Cells(RowIndex=1, ColumnIndex=1), Cell2=worksheet.Cells(RowIndex=1, ColumnIndex=5)).EntireColumn.Select()
```

My question is why does the resize not work as expected, is it a bug? If so, is there a proper place to report it? Should I use the workaround I provided, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for `Resize` in the file `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x8\Range.py` I found the lines:

```
from win32com.client import DispatchBaseClass
class Range(DispatchBaseClass):

  # *irrelevant code in between*

  # Result is of type Range
  # The method GetResize is actually a property, but must be used as a method to correctly pass the arguments
  def GetResize(self, RowSize=defaultNamedOptArg, ColumnSize=defaultNamedOptArg):
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(256, LCID, 2, (9, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17)),RowSize
      , ColumnSize)
    if ret is not None:
      ret = Dispatch(ret, 'GetResize', '{00020846-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}')
    return ret
```

So I tried using `GetResize` instead and it works as `Resize` should work.

```
worksheet.Columns(1).GetResize(ColumnSize=5).Select()
```

There's no `Resize` declared so it actually uses the code:

```
    # Default method for this class is '_Default'
    def __call__(self, RowIndex=defaultNamedOptArg, 
ColumnIndex=defaultNamedOptArg):
        return self._ApplyTypes_(0, 2, (12, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17)), '__call__', None,RowIndex
            , ColumnIndex)
```

So if I rename `GetResize` to `Resize` in that file I can use `Resize` in the code, but that file is created (if it's not already created) by the code [`win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(prog_id='Excel.Application')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127959/win32-dispatch-vs-win32-gencache-in-python-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

In the module `win32com.client.build` the [loop](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/9fbc2ed3c0d69aca2475975a599cc316016599d3/com/win32com/client/build.py#L273) in `DispatchItem.Build`:

```
        for key, item in list(self.propMapGet.items()):
            self._propMapGetCheck_(key,item)
```

Gets the key `'Resize'` and [`_propMapGetCheck_`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/9fbc2ed3c0d69aca2475975a599cc316016599d3/com/win32com/client/build.py#L134) turns it into `GetResize` and adds it to the `mapFuncs` dictionary.

Comment: I'm not the original poster but this amazing answer helped me so much. Thank you!