# How to open a blank excel sheet (not previously saved) using python?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have come across this code snippet to open a blank outlook message window:

```
import win32com.client as client
outlook= client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
message= outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.Display()
```

Now, I am wondering whether using `win32com.client` I can open a blank excel sheet where I want to paste the dataset stored in clipboard, and after saving I want to close the excel sheet. I used to do this manually: copy dataset, open excel, paste in excel, save the excel, and close.

Much thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but `client.Dispatch` can cause *late binding*, which can prevent correct type conversions in some corner cases, and give hard to find errors. `client.gencache.EnsureDispatch` forces early binding. More details on [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50163150/3545273)

Comment: @SergeBallesta I tried all three methods described and it seems that `.gencache.EnsureDispatch` and `.Dispatch` have the same result (see screenshot I added in the answer below).

Comment: @АлексейР: `EnsureDispatch` forces `win32com` to load all definitions for the COM object in a cache. Once the cache has been loaded, `Dispatch` will use it and you will get early binding. But it the cache has never been loaded, `Dispatch` will only give you a late binding proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import win32com.client as client

xl = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()  # create blank workbook
# it is assumed that the clipboard already contains the data to be pasted on the sheet
wb.Sheets(1).Paste(wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1"))  # paste data to Excel
xl.DisplayAlerts = False # not to display a dialog box if a book with this name already exists
wb.Close(True, r'c:\test123.xlsx')  # save & close workbook
xl.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I am very close. Just imagine that I have already copied a data grid from a platform. If I paste it onto a blank excel sheet, the dataset looks like a normal/ regular excel sheet. Now, I would run the above code snippet after I am done copying the data grid.  So, would it be okay to skip df and df.to_clipboard steps, and jump to [ wb.Activesheet.Paste(wb.Activesheet.Range("A1"))  # paste data to Excel ]? If not, what should I do? Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, while running, I get this error:
'<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Workbook instance at 0x1957804710112>' object has no attribute 'Activesheet'

Comment: Updated, see above

Comment: Thanks a lot! It just worked the way I wanted!