# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ActiveSheet' even though the excel workbook is running

Tags: python, excel, automation, attributeerror, win32com

```
import win32com.client

#Attach to the running excel
excel = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.ActiveWorkbook
worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet
active_cell = excel.ActiveCell

#Copy the active cell
active_cell.Copy()
```

I am writing a python script to copy the active cell from an open excel workbook and auto search it online. I have opened the workbook but still got an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ActiveSheet'. Any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to make the excel application visible after the ```excel = win32com.client...``` line.   It is possible that there are no active workbooks when you open Excel.Application.    Perhaps check if workbook is None.  If so, create a new workbook.

Comment: When I try your script (in a Jupyter notebook) it works if Excel is already open, and has a Workbook open. If Excel is open but has no workbook open, it fails with the OP's error. If Excel is not running at all, the `GetActiveObject` call fails. What can happen is that you get "dangling" Excel sessions, where the script has failed but has not released the Excel instance. Always use Task Manager to check that there are no hidden Excel processes running: if there are then your script may be trying to connect to one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetActiveObject is used to connect to any already running Excel instance

If you want to open or create a workbook then

This code will create two workbook objects
Existing Excel file and new created workbook.

```
import win32com.client


excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
# excel.Visible = True  # Workbook visible or not

### Open an existing Excel file
workbook1 = excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Temp\foo.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook1.Worksheets('Sheet1') # or activesheet can be used 

### Create a new workbook with default Sheet
workbook2 = excel.Workbooks.Add()
worksheet2 = workbook2.ActiveSheet
```

Also the following Post on using [Dispatch and encache.EnsureDispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127959/win32-dispatch-vs-win32-gencache-in-python-what-are-the-pros-and-cons) may be useful

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The article is very useful and I do miss the step -  gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application').
When I try to add a new workbook, I encounter a com_error with the following message: "(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Add method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)." Do you have any idea?
I'm wondering if it's possible to not open a new workbook coz I would like to copy the active cell from the currently open Excel file. I don't know why Workbook = None when there is a active workbook from opened excel file.

Comment: The OP's use-case is entirely clear and their code works: just not in some circumstances. The question is why perfectly valid code fails.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's code does work ... *if only one Excel instance is running and has an open workbook*.

When Excel is started by the user from the desktop, once Excel has finished loading it registers itself in the "Running Object Table" (ROT), and is then available for attachment from other processes. When Excel exits, it removes its ROT entry and the process terminates.

The `GetActiveObject` call queries the ROT to find an active instance of the class object specified (in this case `Excel.Application`). If it doesn't find a running instance, it fails.

Unfortunately `GetActiveObject` is not picky. It attaches to the first object it finds in the ROT that matches the class name, which may not be the one you are expecting. Why is this, if there is only one Excel instance in the task bar?

One of the pitfalls of COM code (via win32com in Python or otherwise) is that when you are writing and testing your code it may not always run to completion. The Excel instance to which you have attached may not know if you have finished with it, so hangs around as a background process: *even after you have closed the application on the desktop*. If you do have one of these "orphaned" background processes, it will likely still be in the ROT, and your `GetActiveObject` call may attach to this process rather than the one visible on the desktop.

Get into the habit of checking `Task Manager` if your win32com code is not behaving as you expect. The chances are that you have one or more orphaned Excel background processes. Kill any background Excel processes and try again.